# rails 4 devise 3.2.2 authenticate_user! returns "401 Unauthorized" on json request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, devise

I m using latest version of `rails` (4.0.2), latest `ruby` version (2.0) and latest version of `devise` gem (3.2.2).

When I send JSON request to controller it calls `authenticate_user!` first because it uses

> before_filter : authenticate_user!

As a result of JSON request, it gives `401 Unauthorized` error.

It is working fine with rails 3.2.15 and old devise version.

Comment: Are you sure the json request contain the session info in it I mean does the request contain the valid session cookie

Comment: @Viren yes i check my request headers, it contains HTTP_AUTHORIZATION token like-  request.headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic aVppMTFxSE54aV9YSzZrQjE0emk6WA=="

Comment: Problem is appearing  due to devise token_authentication deprecation and it is resolved now.

Comment: get latest devise version also possibility that you do not have csrf_meta_tags in application layout, gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'rails4'